# How to connect / get password of IBM cloud VPC instacne

Tags: passwords, vpc, ibm-cloud-tools

I've created VPC instance and now I don't know where is the password of that instance. It shows Encrypted password but I don't know how to descrypt it. There is an option labbled "Download RDP File", and it demand password. These is an atrical which shows how to get password but I don't know where to put those commands to get password. Plase help me to get password for my instacne. [image of commands to get your password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIidX.png). [Image of encrypted password and dwonload rdp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv5eR.png).

I just need the password for my instance.